# TreeSet -> Override compareTo in Java

Tags: java, comparable, treeset

First of all, I have this interface:

```
public interface GeometricFigureInterface extends Comparable {

double getArea();

TreeSet<?> getByText(String text);

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o);

}
```

And then a Rectangle

```
public class Dreptunghi implements GeometricFigureInterface {

private double x1;
private double y1;
private double x2;
private double y2;

public Dreptunghi() {
    super();
}

public Dreptunghi(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    super();
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

@Override
public double getArea() {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - y2, 2) + Math.pow(x2 - y2, 2));
}
```

And i have a method that reads from a text the coordonates

```
@Override
public TreeSet<Dreptunghi> getByText(String text) {
    String file ="D:/FiguriGeometrice.txt"; 
    BufferedReader br = null;
    TreeSet<Dreptunghi> setDreptunghiuri = new TreeSet<Dreptunghi>();
    Dreptunghi d = new Dreptunghi();
    try {

        String line = "";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] s = line.split(" ");
            if (s[0].equals("D")) {
                d.setX1(Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
                d.setY1(Double.parseDouble(s[2]));
                d.setX2(Double.parseDouble(s[3]));
                d.setY2(Double.parseDouble(s[4]));
```

//HERE is my problem when I add this the
compareToMethod is called but the objects are the same and i end up with only one object regardless of the values

```
                setDreptunghiuri.add(d);

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ....

    }
    return setDreptunghiuri;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Dreptunghi d = (Dreptunghi)o;
    if(this.getX1() == d.getX1())
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: 1) You only create one instance of the object you're inserting. 2) You should implement #hashCode and #equals.

Comment: Also, your compareTo() method is incorrect. If both objects do not have the same X, you have d1.compareTo(d2) == 1 and d2.compareTo(d1) == 1, which is wrong: an object can't be bigger and lower than another one at the same time.

Comment: @qqilihq: a TreeSet doesn't use equals() and hashCode().

Comment: @JBNizet True, sorry for the false alarm and thank you for correcting. Still, point 1) applies.

Comment: Here is the complete compareTo
if(this.getX1() == d.getX1() && this.getX2() == d.getX2() && this.getY1() == d.getY1()&& this.getY2() == d.getY2())
   return 0;
So if all coordonates are equal then the objects are equal

  else return 1;

Comment: And this is still wrong, for the same reason. Have you read my comment? Why use a TreeSet and a compareTo method if all you care about if if objects are equal or not? If that's what you're after, use a HashSet and implement equals() and hashCode().

Comment: @JB NizetOk, i understand your point. Is it ok now? I compared them by area and if the coordonates are equal then the objects are equal
 public int compareTo(Object o) {
  Dreptunghi other = (Dreptunghi) o;
  
  int areaComp =    Double.valueOf(this.getArea()).compareTo(other.getArea());
  if(areaComp != 0)return areaComp;if (Double.valueOf(this.getX1()).compareTo(other.getX1()) == 0 && Double.valueOf(this.getX2()).compareTo(other.getX2()) == 0
    && Double.valueOf(this.getY1()).compareTo(other.getY1()) == 0 && Double.valueOf(this.getY2()).compareTo(other.getY2()) == 0)
 return 0;
  return 1;

Comment: No, it's still incorrect, since you still unconditionally return 1 if the entities are not equal. You must return a positive integer if this is bigger than other, and a negative integer is this is lower than other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the class inside the loop or only initialise it inside condition

```
if (s[0].equals("D")) {
            Dreptunghi d = new Dreptunghi();
            d.setX1(Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
            d.setY1(Double.parseDouble(s[2]));
            d.setX2(Double.parseDouble(s[3]));
            d.setY2(Double.parseDouble(s[4]));

            setDreptunghiuri.add(d);

        }
```

or

```
 if (s[0].equals("D")) {
                d = new Dreptunghi();
                d.setX1(Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
                d.setY1(Double.parseDouble(s[2]));
                d.setX2(Double.parseDouble(s[3]));
                d.setY2(Double.parseDouble(s[4]));

                setDreptunghiuri.add(d);

            }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But what would the explanation be :)?

Comment: @alex1111 You end up with only one object because in the code in the OP you only make one.

Comment: you have created the object outside the condition.So only one object will be created and same is added in the treeset.Running code:in every loop u r going to create new object and added in the set.